# Cannot create an array of nested object using a project operation

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I'm forced to use the **aggregation** framework and the **project** operation of **Spring Data MongoDb**.

What I'd like to do is creating an array of object as a result of a project operation.

For example, considering this intermediate aggregation result:

```
[
  {
    "content": {
      "processes": [
        {
          "id": "101a",
          "title": "delivery"
        },
        {
          "id": "101b",
          "title": "feedback"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

What I want to obtain is this:

```
[  
  {
    "results":
    {
      "titles": [
        {
          "id": "101a",
          "value": "delivery"
        },
        {
          "id": "101b",
          "value": "feedback"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

This was just an example, I don't want to simply "rename" some fields.
What I want is the possibility to create an array of objects.

If I try something like this:

```
   projectionOperation
     .and("$content.processes.id").as("results.titles.id")
     .and("$content.processes.title").as("results.titles.value");
```

I obtain this:

```
[  
  {
    "results":
    {
      "titles": {
          "id": ["101a", "101b"]
          "value": ["delivery", "feedback"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

With this projection the array is created, but not "in the proper position".

However, If I use the *nested* operator, I haven't figure out a way to specify that I want to create an array instead of an object. 
With this projection:

```
projectionOperation.and("results.titles")
         .nested(
              bind("id", "process.id")
                 .and("value", "process.title")
         );
```

I can create a proper nested object but not into an array:

```
"results.titles": {
            "id": "101b",
            "value": "feedback"
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the java code that you have tried ?

Comment: @Veeram I've updated the question

Comment: I've tried to use arrayOf(), projectOperation.and(arrayOf("results.titles")).nested(bind(...)), without any luck

Comment: Hi @Veeram , I've added a similar question. I would appreciate a lot if you could take a look. It's https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52492829/cannot-use-nested-variableoperators-mapitemsof-in-spring-data-mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation code.

```
ProjectionOperation po = Aggregation.project().and(
   VariableOperators.mapItemsOf("content.processes").as("rt")
    .andApply(
      new AggregationExpression() {
       @Override
       public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext aggregationOperationContext) {
             return new Document("id", "$$rt.id").append("value", "$$rt.title");
       }
    } 
  )
).as("result");
```