# Cannot use Nested VariableOperators.mapItemsOf in Spring Data MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I'm forced to use the **aggregation** framework and the **project** operation of **Spring Data MongoDb**.

What I'd like to do is creating an array of object as a result of a project operation.

Considering this intermediate aggregation result:

```
{
  "processes": [
    {
      "id": "101a",
      "assignees": [
        {
          "id": "201a",
          "username": "carl93"
        },
        {
          "id": "202a",
          "username": "susan"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "101b",
      "assignees": [
        {
          "id": "201a",
          "username": "carl93"
        },
        {
          "id": "202a",
          "username": "susan"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to get for each process, all the assignee usernames and ids. Hence, what I want to obtain is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "results": [
      {
        "id": "201a",
        "value": "carl93",
        "parentObjectId": "101a"
      },
      {
        "id": "202a",
        "value": "susan",
        "parentObjectId": "101a"
      },
      {
        "id": "201a",
        "value": "carl93",
        "parentObjectId": "101b"
      },
      {
        "id": "202a",
        "value": "susan",
        "parentObjectId": "101b"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

To reach this goal I'm using 2 nested VariableOperators.mapItemsOf obtaining:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Cannot convert [Document{{id= 201a, value= carl93, parentObjectId= 101a}}, Document{{id= 202a, value = susan, parentObjectId= 101a}}]
of type class java.util.ArrayList into an instance of class java.lang.Object! 
Implement a custom Converter<class java.util.ArrayList, class java.lang.Object> and register it with the CustomConversions.
```

Here's the code that I'm currently using:

```
new ProjectionOperation().and(
    VariableOperators.mapItemsOf("processes")
      .as("pr")
      .andApply(
           VariableOperators.mapItemsOf("$pr.ownership.assignees")
               .as("ass")
               .andApply(aggregationOperationContext -> {
           Document document = new Document();

           document.append("id", "$$ass.id");
           document.append("value", "$$ass.username");
           document.append("parentObjectId", "$$pr.id");

           return document;
          })
    )
).as("results");
```

The code produces this:

```
[ 
  [
    {
      "id": "201a",
      "value": "carl93",
      "parentObjectId": "101a"
    },
    {
      "id": "202a",
      "value": "susan",
      "parentObjectId": "101a"
    }
  ], 
  [
    {
      "id": "201a",
      "value": "carl93",
      "parentObjectId": "101b"
    },
    {
      "id": "202a",
      "value": "susan",
      "parentObjectId": "101b"
    }
  ]
]
```

As you can see there are 2 nested arrays, [[],[]]. This is the reason why the exception is thrown. 
Nevertheless what I want to obtain is just one array, adding all the objects in it (possibly without duplicates or null values). I've tried the addToSet operator and other aggregtion operators, without any success.

Comment: I don't see why you get nulls and 4 elements when you're sample document has only two elements. Are you sure you have the right document in the question ?

Comment: Good point, I've written this question starting from a more complicated example. The null values are not compliant to the initial example. Hence, just forget about the null values. What is messing things ups is the array of arrays structure that comes from the 2 nested VariableOperators.mapItemsOf()

Comment: did you intend to include `results` field for each array element in the `processes` ? That is the only difference I see between output.

Comment: I've updated the question, with the proper goal I want to reach and removing the null values that weren't compliant to the initial example.

Answer (score 3):

Use `$reduce` with `$concatArrays` to join the arrays.

```
 new ProjectionOperation().and(
    ArrayOperators.arrayOf("processes")
      .reduce(ArrayOperators.ConcatArrays.arrayOf("$$value").concat(
           VariableOperators.mapItemsOf("$$this.ownership.assignees")
               .as("ass")
               .andApply(aggregationOperationContext -> {
           Document document = new Document();
           document.append("id", "$$ass.id");
           document.append("value", "$$ass.username");
           document.append("parentObjectId", "$$this.id");
           return document;
          })
    )).startingWith(Arrays.asList())
).as("results");
```

Comment: Nice approach! But I obtain
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference '$$value'!`

Comment: I have a misplaced braces. Try now and it works in my version 2.0.4 spring mongo jar.

Comment: I had noticed the misplaced brace. I obtain `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference '$$value'!`. What is the purpose of `$$value`? Moreover, I've tried to place the content of `concat` inside `arrayOf` with bad results :(

Comment: `$$value` keeps accumulated values as we concat array elements  inside `$reduce` operation. `$$this` refers to the current element in iteration. More [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/). What is your spring mongo version ? Do you have the right imports ?

Comment: <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
<version>2.0.8.RELEASE</version>

Comment: Can you show me the code you use to invoke aggregation  query with mongotemplate ? It worked for me when I use `mongoTemplate.aggregate(newAggregation(project), colname, Document.class)`

Comment: mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, COLLECTION,ConfigurationResult.class);
Do you want the mongoTemplate configuration? (it's pretty standard)
The aggregation has 9 stages, if you want I can send it to you.

Comment: That's not needed. COLLECTION - Is this an input pojo or collection name ? It looks like  spring is trying to validate your field name instead of passing it directly with your set up. That explains why it would work with Document.class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180749/discussion-between-desoss-and-veeram).

Comment: no, I got problems both with $$value and with null values t

Comment: what exactly is the problem ? Can you explain with an example may be?